# Sharing multiple folders between linux and windows in QEMU

Tags: qemu

With an option like `-netdev user,net=10.0.2.0/24,id=host_files,restrict=off,smb=/home/mahmood,smbserver=10.0.2.4`, I can share the home folder and my linux home is accessible from windows by mapping `\\10.0.2.4\qemu`.

However, I want to know how can I share multiple folders? Using `smb=/home/mahmood,smbserver=10.0.2.4,smb=/etc,smbserver=10.0.2.5` is not correct.

Comment: According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU#QEMU's_built-in_SMB_server   "If you are using sharing options multiple times like `-net user,smb=shared_dir_path1 -net user,smb=shared_dir_path2` or `-net user,smb=shared_dir_path1,smb=shared_dir_path2` then it will share only the last defined one." so what you want may not be possible with these options and you may just need to run a full smb server

Answer (score 0):

You can modify and reload the smb.conf file created by QEMU.

The file can be found in `/tmp/qemu-smb.*/smb.conf`, where `*` is a random string changing on every QEMU run.  Do the changes you need or replace the file with your own.

Once you've made the changes, the samba server can be forced to reload the config file with `smbcontrol all reload-config` (as root) or `killall -HUP smbd`.

This can be automated by adding the relevant lines to your QEMU start script (the details depend on the wrapper you're using).